# Duplicate rows - how to remove one?

Tags: postgresql, duplication

I have a pretty large table (~114 million rows) containing OS MasterMap data. This is freshly loaded data in a new table. When trying to set the primary key, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "tbl_os_mmap_topoarea_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (toid)=(1000000004081308) is duplicated.
```

Somehow, I have ended up with an **exactly duplicated** row. Every field is the same in these two rows. I want to delete one row, but keep the other. As there is no way to distinguish between the two, how can this be done?

I would like to do this as quickly and simply as possible. Creating temporary tables etc. is not really an option as it would take too long on a dataset of this size. Creating a new unique ID column would be quicker I guess, but also probably take some time.

After a bit of research, I have learned that all records in postgres have a hidden unique id, the ctid. Can I use this to delete one of the duplicate rows?

Comment: Perform a query to find duplicated rows.

Comment: @Vérace I already did that. But then how can I delete just one of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work I think:

```
with d as 
  ( select ctid, row_number() over (partition by t.*) as rn 
    from tablename as t 
  ) 
delete from tablename as t 
using d 
where d.rn > 1 
  and d.ctid = t.ctid ;
```

And another variation. Not sure which will be more efficient:

```
delete from tablename as t 
where exists 
      ( select * 
        from tablename as d 
        where d.ctid > t.ctid 
          and d.* is not distinct from t.*
      ) ;
```

But note what the docs say abut `ctid`:

> `ctid`
>
> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the `ctid` can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's `ctid` will change if it is updated or moved by `VACUUM FULL`. Therefore `ctid` is useless as a long-term row identifier. The `OID`, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

So, if the table was created `WITH OIDS`, use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ypercube. Your mention of OIDs lead me to double check. My table did have OIDs, so I was able to use those to remove the duplicate row.

Comment: Nice. I'm not cure `ctid` might be ok as well in a single statement/transaction. The problems may appear in long running transactions or other operations that take longer. See also the duplicate question and its answers, for other options.

Comment: As a data point, I had a table with ~85000 rows containing ~4000 duplicates, and the first version of this query was _far_ more performant for me - it finished almost instantly, while the second version was timing out after 2 hours.